# Deploy Jhipster on clevercloud

Tags: maven, deployment, war, jhipster

I'm deploying a Jhipster application on Clevercloud.

I have set up some configuration:

war.json

```
{
   "build": {
      "type": "maven",
      "goal": "package -Pprod -DskipTests"
   },
   "deploy": {
      "goal": "package -Pprod -DskipTests",
      "container": "TOMCAT8",
      "war": [
         {
            "file": "target/myapp-1.0.0.war"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

maven.json

```
{
  "build": {
      "type": "maven",
      "goal": "package -Pprod -DskipTests"
  },
  "deploy": {
    "goal": "package -Pprod -DskipTests"
  }
}
```

I have modified the application-prod.yml to include the url/username/password of the db add-on.

When I deploy, the deployment is successfull but the application is not running.

On the application page I have 404 error.
The DB is correctly initialised.
In the logs I have the following messages that I don't understand or I'm not able to solve:

multiple times this message

```
2017-09-18T09:21:22.701Z: 09:21:21.483 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.exception-conversion-word]
2017-09-18T09:21:22.702Z: 09:21:21.486 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.exception-conversion-word] not found - trying original name [logging.exception-conversion-word]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [logging.exception-conversion-word] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.exception-conversion-word].
2017-09-18T09:21:22.702Z: 09:21:21.486 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.exception-conversion-word]
2017-09-18T09:21:22.702Z: 09:21:21.486 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [logging.exception-conversion-word] threw NamingException with message: Name [logging.exception-conversion-word] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.exception-conversion-word].. Returning null.
```

then:

```
2017-09-18T09:21:22.777Z: [09:21:12.705][debug][talledLocalContainer]   Connection attempt with socket Socket[unconnected], current time is 1505726472705
2017-09-18T09:21:22.778Z: [09:21:12.705][debug][talledLocalContainer]   Socket Socket[unconnected] for port 8009 closed
2017-09-18T09:21:22.778Z: [09:21:13.068][debug][talledLocalContainer] Executing '/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/icedtea8/jre/bin/java' with arguments:
2017-09-18T09:21:22.778Z: '-version'
2017-09-18T09:21:22.778Z: The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
2017-09-18T09:21:22.778Z: not part of the command.
2017-09-18T09:21:22.779Z: [09:21:13.085][debug][talledLocalContainer] Output appended to /tmp/cargo-jvm-version-4176730048875251522.txt
2017-09-18T09:21:22.779Z: [09:21:13.085][debug][talledLocalContainer] Error appended to /tmp/cargo-jvm-version-4176730048875251522.txt
2017-09-18T09:21:22.779Z: [09:21:13.086][debug][talledLocalContainer] Project base dir set to: /home/bas/app_4b724c3b-6703-474e-9ec4-65d775cd0013
2017-09-18T09:21:22.779Z: [09:21:13.086][debug][talledLocalContainer] Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing '/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/icedtea8/jre/bin/java' with arguments:
2017-09-18T09:21:22.779Z: '-version'
2017-09-18T09:21:22.779Z: The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
2017-09-18T09:21:22.779Z: not part of the command.
```

And multiples times:

```
2017-09-18T09:21:22.793Z: [09:21:13.416][debug][URLDeployableMonitor] Checking URL [http://localhost:8080/cargocpc/index.html] for status using a timeout of [120000] ms...
2017-09-18T09:21:22.794Z: [09:21:13.452][debug][URLDeployableMonitor] URL [http://localhost:8080/cargocpc/index.html] is not responding: -1 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2017-09-18T09:21:22.794Z: [09:21:13.452][debug][URLDeployableMonitor] Notifying monitor listener [org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.DeployerWatchdog@7bd4937b]
```

Ending with:

```
2017-09-18T09:21:32.710Z: 2017-09-18 09:21:28.724  INFO 2232 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.bbs.dm.config.WebConfigurer          : Web application configuration, using profiles: prod
2017-09-18T09:21:32.711Z: 2017-09-18 09:21:28.735  INFO 2232 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.bbs.dm.config.WebConfigurer          : Web application fully configured
2017-09-18T09:21:32.711Z: 2017-09-18 09:21:28.994 DEBUG 2232 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Starting Liquibase synchronously
2017-09-18T09:21:36.985Z: Nothing listening on 8080. Please update your configuration and redeploy
2017-09-18T09:21:52.730Z: 2017-09-18 09:21:47.492 DEBUG 2232 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Started Liquibase in 18498 ms
2017-09-18T09:21:57.985Z: Application start successful
2017-09-18T09:21:57.985Z: No cron to setup
2017-09-18T09:21:57.986Z: Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/zabbix-agentd.service → /usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/systemd/system/zabbix-agentd.service.
```

I have done nothing else except following [Clevercloud documentation to deploy](https://www.clever-cloud.com/doc/clever-cloud-overview/add-application/)

Have I miss something in the configuration?
(For info, the application is deploying well on other platform like Heroku or Pivotal)

Comment: So it seems your app is deployed in Tomcat8 but how did you set the spring profile? This is not the preferred way to run a JHipster app, it's usually much simpler to run the executable war with `java -jar target/*.war --spring.profiles.active=prod`

Comment: Do you know how I should modify the configuration to not deploy in Tomcat8?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with clevercloud, you should contact them. They could also contribute a module to deploy, same as what we have already for heroku, openshift, cloudfoundry, ...

Comment: We tried, well someone from the comunity tried, but it was not pursued https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/1655

Comment: If you want to execute the war directly you can replace the deploy section with   "deploy": { "jarName": "target/myapp-1.0.0.war"  }

Comment: It works with jarName in war.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy a jhipster application on Clevercloud.
Here is what worked for me.

I have followed the indications given [to create an application](https://www.clever-cloud.com/doc/clever-tools/create/) and [deploy it](https://www.clever-cloud.com/doc/clever-cloud-overview/add-application/?search=create)  using [the CLI](https://www.clever-cloud.com/doc/clever-tools/getting_started/)

Configuration files:

clevercloud/war.json

```
{
   "build": {
      "type": "maven",
      "goal": "package -Pprod -DskipTests"
   },
   "deploy": {
      "jarName": "target/myapp-1.0.0.war"
   }
}
```

clevercloud/maven.json

```
{
  "build": {
      "type": "maven",
      "goal": "package -Pprod -DskipTests"
  },
  "deploy": {
    "goal": "package -Pprod -DskipTests"
  }
}
```

I modified my application-prod.yml to link the db.